# [ MongoNetworkError ], when I deploy on Heroku, the App doesn't connect to mongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, heroku, redux

I created full stack Shopping List App (basically same as To Do List) with mongoDB, Express, React and Node. It works on my local environment. But when I try to run the App on Heroku, I get error with mongoDB connection.
It says :

```
{ MongoNetworkError: connection 5 to cluster0-shopping-list-2-shard-00-02-0rerl.mongodb.net:27017 closed
name: 'MongoNetworkError',
errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
[Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

I use mongoDB Atlas and I already set my IP address to white list in the cluster on Atlas.

Here are my codes:

config/keys.js

```
module.exports = {
    mongoURI: 'mongodb+srv://<Username>:<myUserPassword>3@cluster0-shopping-list-2-0rerl.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true'
}
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const path = require('path');
const items = require('./routes/api/items');
const app = express();

// Body-parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// db config
const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

// connect to Mongo
mongoose
    .connect(db, { useNewUrlParser: true})
    .then(() => console.log('MongoDB connected...'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

// Use Routes
app.use('/api/items', items)

// Serve static assets if in production
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    // Set static folder
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}.`));
```

package.json (I show this because this might be related to this issue.)

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
  },
```

I expect the App to show item list that mongoDB collection has. And I want to allow users to add new items. But it doesn't show any items even though I can see some items exist in MongoDB collection and it works in my local environment.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing your config is in your `.ignore` is that correct?

Comment: No...I only have node_modules in .gitignore

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: check if there is /build in .gitignore file in client side

Answer (score 0):

You are running npm run server and client but server and client scripts are not defined in your package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon server/server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  }
```

Have you set config vars in heroku setting of your project for database connection mongoURI and PORT.